# How to create graphs of relative frequency from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I know that it's possible to create a histogram from a pandas dataframe column with matplotlib.pyplot using the code:

```
df.plot.hist(y='Distance')
```

Which creates a graph like this:

[image: Graph one]

However what I'm looking for is a plot of relative frequency, expressed as a percentage of the total. I'd also like for the graph to have an overflow bin at 300 so that it looks something along the lines of:
[image: Graph two]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
orders = [{'number': 1029,'brand':'XPTO','qty':50},
      {'number': 3233,'brand':'ABCD','qty':50},
      {'number': 5455,'brand':'XPTO','qty':50},
      {'number': 1234,'brand':'ABCD','qty':50},
      {'number': 7654,'brand':'TXWZ','qty':50},
      {'number': 8765,'brand':'XPTO','qty':50},
      {'number': 4354,'brand':'TXWZ','qty':50},
      {'number': 9089,'brand':'XPTO','qty':50},
      {'number': 1031,'brand':'XPTO','qty':50}]
orders_df = pd.DataFrame(orders)
series = orders_df['brand'].value_counts() / len(orders_df)
indx = [0,1,2]
plt.bar(indx, series*100)
plt.ylabel('%')
plt.title('Relative fequency')
plt.xticks(indx, series.index)
```

[image: Relative frequency]

Comment: You can use series = orders_df['brand'].value_counts(True) which normalizes automatically without having to divide by len(orders_df)

Comment: since you *100, these are now percentage frequencies